# Mysql: Stored procedure to change the "table name" in a query based on user-name logged in

Tags: mysql

I have **two tables** `employee` and `employee2` which is altered version of employee, both save in same schema company in my **mysql database**

How is it possible (if possible) to change the employee to employee2 in a query made by a user which is authorized to connect to mysql but is not supposed to see the original data but the altered data which is already in employee2. i.e.

query made by user **admin**:

```
select * from employee;
```

should be executed as

```
select * from employee;
```

But
query made by user **guest**:

```
select * from employee;
```

should be executed as:

```
select * from employee2;
```

without guest knowing that.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with MySQL only based on authenticated login - or are you utilizing another server side language to handle this? :)

Comment: I would want base on MYSQL user name and password only, and the MYSQL to handle it without guest knowing he/she see different data. Thanks

Comment: Where are they logging in then to view the MySQL data, via what system?

Comment: Through MySQL terminal. Like in linux using  `mysql -u username -ppassword` and in windows through command line